# Using different ICE servers for WebRTC connection

Tags: twilio, webrtc, stun, turn, ice

Should both parties in the WebRTC connection use the same ICE servers? What is the risk of using different ICE servers or even TURN providers at the same time by different sides of the call?

For example, I wonder about a situation where

1. client1 uses Xirsys STUN/TURN servers
2. client2 uses Twilio STUN/TURN servers
3. Or just about an edge case where client1 uses Twilio East US, and client2 West US.

In many places I see notes saying that only one client should receive ICE servers and send them to the second client. But why? Shouldn't clients use their closest servers to improve overall performance? Since TURN is just a technology, location of the server or provider shouldn't matter.

In the book **WebRTC for the Curious** I see paragraph about [TURN permission policy](https://github.com/webrtc-for-the-curious/webrtc-for-the-curious/blob/366f94b47df60d071fe7ea9d5e8da85db8207624/content/docs/03-connecting.md#permissions)

> The remote host needs to give you the IP and port as it appears to the TURN server. This means it should send a STUN Binding Request to the TURN Server. A common error case is that a remote host will send a STUN Binding Request to a different server. They will then ask you to create a permission for this IP.

So, it sounds like using different ICE servers may lead to situation where the client2 is unable to establish a direct connection to a client1 TURN server (Twilio), because NAT Mapping has Address Dependent Mapping to Xirsys STUN server.

```
client1 <--> client1 TURN Twilio <--> srfx client2 
(failed, client2 cannot receive data from client1 TURN server because of the NAT Mapping is Address Dependant and it was created for Xirys, not Twilio)
```

and because of that, it will be forced to use two TURN servers.

```
client1 <--> client1 TURN Twilio <--> client2 TURN Xirsys <--> client2
```

So, is using different ICE servers a risk that connection will be handled by two TURN servers instead of only one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In WebRTC, is it required for participants to be connected to the same TURN server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333849/in-webrtc-is-it-required-for-participants-to-be-connected-to-the-same-turn-serv)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer doesn't explain the following situation:
client2 calls Xirsys STUN with STUN Binding request. A new mapped address is created on the NAT of the client, the mapping is Address Dependent.
Later on, client2 asks for permission to send&receive packets from client1 TURN server. Unfortunately because NAT Mapping is Address Dependent, all inbound traffic will be dropped. 

Or did I get it wrong? Maybe client2 will try to use client1 TURN as a STUN server during the ICE candidates scan?

Comment: Such NAT configurations are rare and will typically fall back to relay-relay connections. And there is always the option to disable the permissions mechanism ("server relay" for coturn)

Comment: You are right that if Address Depend NATs are in use it will increase the likeliness that double TURN will be used in the end.
But I highly doubt that giving your local TURN server as a STUN server to the remote endpoint helps, because it would require the ICE stack of the remote endpoint to actually rely on using for binding response from that specific STUN/TURN server as the information for the permission request. And I'm not aware that any ICE stack out there would guarantee something like this.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I also learned that ICE connectivity checks perform STUN requests, so a check from peer to client TURN server will also help to discover peer client addresses. If discovered peer public addresses will be different than one from the candidate's list, it will be marked as peer reflexive candidate.